# Nutch + Solr on top level page only

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, nutch

I've been trying to use Nutch to crawl over over the first page of the domains in my urls file and then use Solr to make keywords in the crawled data searchable. So far I haven't been able to get anything working this way, unless the two pages are linked together.

I realize this is probably an issue of the pages having no incoming links, and therefore the PageRank algorithm discards the page content. I tried adjusting the parameters so that the default score is higher for urls not in the graph, but I'm still getting the same results.

Is there anything people know of that can build an index over pages with no incoming links?

Thanks!

Comment: It's tough to understand (could be just me) how your first paragraph (fetch via nutch and content in solr for search) is related to the second (pagerank). What exactly are you trying to do? Once content is indexed in solr with the searchable fields and criteria configured, it should work irrespective of links unless you're setting up something link specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try a nutch inject command to insert the "no-incomming-link" URL into the nutch DB.

I guess that if you don't see anything in your solr indexes, it is because no data for those URLs is stored in the nutch DB (since nutch will take care to sync its DB with the indexes). Not having data in the DB may be explained by the fact that the URLs are isolated, hence you can try the inject command to include those sites.

I would try to actually see the internal DB to verify the nutch behavior, since before inserting values in the indexes, nutch stores data inside its DBs.

Assigning a higher score has no effect, since lucene will give you a result as long as the data is in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Solr now reads HTML files using Tika by default, so that's not a problem.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TikaEntityProcessor

If all you want is listed pages, is there a specific reason to use the Nutch crawler?  Or could you just feed URLs to Solr and go from there?